# in function "isDigit" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Tags: java, string, encryption, char, syntax-error

I need to write encryptor.
The first letter needs to be converted to its ASCII code.
The second letter needs to be switched with the last letter

It should make from this "65 119esi 111dl 111lw 108dvei 105n 97n 111ka"
This "A wise old owl lived in an oak"

But when I check is char a digit i have an error.

```
public static void encryptThis(String text) {
        String [] text_arr = text.split("\\s");

        for(int i = 0; i < text_arr.length;i++){
            String word = text_arr[i];

            int length = word.length();

            char [] char_word = new char [length];

            char_word = word.toCharArray();
            int k = 0;

            length = char_word.length;

            char [] numb = new char [length];

            for (int j = 0;j < length; j++){



     //In this place
               if (Character.isDigit(char_word[i])){
                   numb[k] = char_word[i];
                   char_word[i] = ' ';
                   k++;
                   System.out.println(numb[k]);
               }
            }
            int number = Integer.parseInt(numb.toString(),8);
            String edit_char_word = char_word.toString();
            String final_str = new StringBuffer(edit_char_word).reverse().toString().trim();
            final_str = number + final_str;
            text_arr[i] = final_str;

        }
        String fin_text = text_arr.toString();
        return fin_text;

    }
```

Comment: Do you mean `Character.isDigit(char_word[j])`?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the encryptThis method from the beginning and tried to stay as simple to get readable code, here is
a full working example. As you did not mention what to do if a number is the first "letter" there is no
special handling for this - an "1" will be encrypted to (ascii) 49...

```
public class Main_So {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62460366/in-function-isdigit-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-5");
        String input = "A wise old owl lived in an oak";
        String outputExpected = "65 119esi 111dl 111lw 108dvei 105n 97n 111ka";
        System.out.println("input:              " + input);
        String output = encryptThis(input);
        System.out.println("output encryptThis: " + output);
        System.out.println("output expected:    " + outputExpected);
    }

    public static String encryptThis(String text) {
        String[] text_arr = text.split("\\s");
        String outputString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < text_arr.length; i++) {
            String word = text_arr[i];
            int length = word.length();
            int ascii0 = (int) word.charAt(0);
            String word0 = String.valueOf(ascii0); // first char as ascii code
            String subString = word.substring(1);
            if (length > 2) { // switch chars if string length > 2
                char char1 = word.charAt(1);
                char charEnd = word.charAt(length - 1);
                StringBuilder wordBuilder = new StringBuilder(subString);
                wordBuilder.setCharAt(0, charEnd);
                wordBuilder.setCharAt((length - 2), char1);
                subString = String.valueOf(wordBuilder);
            }
            outputString = outputString + word0 + subString + " ";
        }
        return outputString;
    }
}
```

This is the result:

```
input:              A wise old owl lived in an oak
output encryptThis: 65 119esi 111dl 111lw 108dvei 105n 97n 111ka 
output expected:    65 119esi 111dl 111lw 108dvei 105n 97n 111ka
```